# Should I format some code in the title of a question?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, code-formatting, title

I always try to avoid inserting some function name (or class, method, etc.) in the title of the question, but sometimes I just can't.

In those cases, how should I format the function name? For example, should it be

**[Difference between `mod` and `rem` in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5891140/297114)**

or just

**Difference between mod and rem in Haskell?**

There are some scenarios where it is obvious you're including some function name in your question (like **Problems with print() Python**, etc.), but in my example, it isn't.

Comment: Code formatting does not work in titles, so it's pretty much irrelevant. You can put quotes to make it stick out: *Difference between "mod" and "rem" in Haskell?*